# Calculating minutes within a defined time window?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am looking to calculate the minutes spent performing a task that is within a specific time window.

I have the two input parameters defining the time window `@WindowStart` and  `@WindowEnd` and i have [Task Start] and [Task End] columns in my task table.

What would be the easiest way to calculate the time spent on a task that is within my time window? Tasks can easily begin or end after `@WindowStart` and `@WindowEnd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to find the length of tasks are entirely contained in the window:

```
select [task end] - [task start] as taskDuration
from tasktable
where [task start] > @WindowStart and [task end] < @WindowEnd
```

If instead you want to look at durations that have any overlap with the window, just flip the and to an or.

Comment: I ended up using a combination of your input and a UDF to calculate what part was with in the selected window

Answer (score 0):

This might work? If the task start / end times are outside of the window start / end times, the difference would be negative. There are a few scenarios:

```
select TestDates.*,
 DATEDIFF(minute, 
   CASE WHEN TestDates.WindowStart > TestDates.TaskStart 
        THEN TestDates.WindowStart ELSE TestDates.TaskStart END, 
   CASE WHEN TestDates.WindowEnd < TestDates.TaskEnd
        THEN TestDates.WindowEnd ELSE TestDates.TaskEnd END
         ) as Interval
 from
(
SELECT GETDATE() as WindowStart,
dateadd(minute, 10, GETDATE()) as WindowEnd,
dateadd(minute, 2, GETDATE()) as TaskStart,
dateadd(minute, 14, GETDATE()) as TaskEnd
) as TestDates


select TestDates.*,
 DATEDIFF(minute, 
   CASE WHEN TestDates.WindowStart > TestDates.TaskStart 
        THEN TestDates.WindowStart ELSE TestDates.TaskStart END, 
   CASE WHEN TestDates.WindowEnd < TestDates.TaskEnd
        THEN TestDates.WindowEnd ELSE TestDates.TaskEnd END
         ) as Interval
 from
(
SELECT GETDATE() as WindowStart,
dateadd(minute, 10, GETDATE()) as WindowEnd,
dateadd(minute, -2, GETDATE()) as TaskStart,
dateadd(minute, 20, GETDATE()) as TaskEnd
) as TestDates

select TestDates.*,
 DATEDIFF(minute, 
   CASE WHEN TestDates.WindowStart > TestDates.TaskStart 
        THEN TestDates.WindowStart ELSE TestDates.TaskStart END, 
   CASE WHEN TestDates.WindowEnd < TestDates.TaskEnd
        THEN TestDates.WindowEnd ELSE TestDates.TaskEnd END
         ) as Interval
 from
(
SELECT GETDATE() as WindowStart,
dateadd(minute, 10, GETDATE()) as WindowEnd,
dateadd(minute, 20, GETDATE()) as TaskStart,
dateadd(minute, 30, GETDATE()) as TaskEnd
) as TestDates

select TestDates.*,
 DATEDIFF(minute, 
   CASE WHEN TestDates.WindowStart > TestDates.TaskStart 
        THEN TestDates.WindowStart ELSE TestDates.TaskStart END, 
   CASE WHEN TestDates.WindowEnd < TestDates.TaskEnd
        THEN TestDates.WindowEnd ELSE TestDates.TaskEnd END
         ) as Interval
 from
(
SELECT GETDATE() as WindowStart,
dateadd(minute, 10, GETDATE()) as WindowEnd,
dateadd(minute, -20, GETDATE()) as TaskStart,
dateadd(minute, -10, GETDATE()) as TaskEnd
) as TestDates
```

Comment: Doesn't quite catch the situation where TaskEnd is before WindowStart

Comment: Hmm, I had created 4 test cases in my original post, the last one being the case where TaskEnd is before WindowStart. I just retested it and it seems to work for me. What didn't quite catch for you?

Comment: My bad, hadn't seen that you mentioned on top that you'd get negative numbers in case there was no overlap.... To me that seems like 'not what we want', but then again, the 'specs' are kind of meagre on the details ...

Comment: Yes a negative value is likely not a value Peter would want returned, but I'm sure that he could figure out the next steps from it. Or derive an update to it that would wind up looking , or update my solution to derive a solution from it that would look nearly identical to yours

Answer (score 0):

Simply shift the start / end of the task to the appropriate limits.
Mind that this requires that start-time comes before end-time, if any of the pairs is reversed you'll need to shift them around first or you'll get strange results. Then again, when ever is end before start in the real world ? =)

```
DECLARE @task_start   datetime,
        @task_end     datetime,
        @window_start datetime,
        @window_end   datetime

SELECT @window_start = '09:00',
       @window_end   = '17:00',
       @task_start = '11:15',
       @task_end   = '19:22'

SELECT time_spent = (CASE WHEN @task_start > @window_end   THEN 0
                          WHEN @task_end   < @window_start THEN 0
                          ELSE DateDiff(minute, (CASE WHEN @task_start < @window_start THEN @window_start
                                                                                       ELSE @task_start END),
                                                (CASE WHEN @task_end > @window_end THEN @window_end
                                                                                   ELSE @task_end END))
                              END)
```